# pointer returned by shmat points at the end of address space which gives seg fault

Tags: c++, linux, new-operator, shared-memory, memory-alignment

```
 //TeamSize is an integer   
int Seg_id = shmget(SHM_KEY,sizeof(Word)*TeamSize,IPC_CREAT);

void* Seg_ptr = shmat(Seg_id,0,0);

new(Seg_ptr) Word[TeamSize];
```

I am having trouble with this segment of code. The Word class is a class that I defined with 8 bytes char array and some parse functions. I think I am using shmget and shmat just like how others use them. But I keep getting seg fault. When I print out Seg_id, it looks normal just some number. But Seg_ptr points at 0xffffffffffffffff. Then the next line of code obviously gives me seg fault. I want to know why Seg_ptr points at the end of memory space. Thanks in advance!

Comment: So shmat is returning `-1`. Which means there's an error. Check errno in that case to determine what the error is.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I got errno = 13 which is permission denied. What can possibly be the cause?
I am running these codes in a member function of one of my class. Would it lead to this kind of error?

Comment: You may want to check that your `Seg_id` is "good" as well. If that is `-1`, then I expect you won't get a good error from `shmat` either.

Comment: my Seg_id is 524290 (ran it a couple of times). So it is probably good

Comment: Have you read the documentation for `shmat`? It lists what can cause the various error codes.

Comment: Also look up `shmget`. You're being denied permission; how do you think the permissions are set?

Comment: I am not sure, I am pretty new to this. I think I wrote some pretty normal codes. I am compiling it remotely on Prof's server. So it could be the system's issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After testing, it seems that non-root user cannot use shmat or it will return Permission Denied.

late update:
  setting permission helps, such as  shmget(SHM_KEY, sizeof(...),(IPC_CREAT | 0666)).But I kept getting invalid argument with this ; it turned out shared memory segment with the same key already existed. I could then use ipcs to check if I already have the shared memory segment with the same key and use ipcrm to free it.