# Implementing shared memory without root privilege

Tags: c, linux, ipc, shared-memory

I have the following C program

```
#include <stdio.h>                                                                        
#include <sys/types.h>                                                                    
#include <sys/shm.h>                                                                      
#include <sys/ipc.h>                                                                      

int main()                                                                                
{                                                                                         
  key_t shm_key;                                                                          
  int shm_flag,shm_id,shm_size;                                                           
  void *shm_addr;                                                                         

  shm_key = ftok("/home/meow/Arena",22);                                                  
  perror("SHMKEY");                                                                       

  shm_id = shmget(shm_key,sizeof(int)*20,IPC_CREAT);                                      
  perror("SHMGET");                                                                       

  shm_addr = shmat(shm_id,NULL,0);                                                        
  perror("SHMAT");                                                                     

}
```

when execute without root privilege I get

```
meow@darkArts ~/Arena/c $ gcc shm.c && ./a.out 
SHMKEY: Success
SHMGET: Success
SHMAT: Permission denied
```

And when executed by the root user I get the following message

```
root@darkArts:/home/meow/Arena/c# gcc shm.c && ./a.out
SHMKEY: Success
SHMGET: Success
SHMAT: Success
```

**Is it possible to bind the shared memory to my address space without the root privileges ?**

### EDIT:

 With `shmid = shmget(key, SHMSZ, IPC_CREAT | 0666);` and `shmid = shmget(key, SHMSZ, IPC_CREAT | 0777);` I get

```
meow@darkArts ~/Arena/c $ gcc shm.c && ./a.out 
SHMKEY: Success
SHMGET: Permission denied
SHMAT: Invalid argument
```

Comment: Call `perror()` **only** if a function indicated a failure.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19075589/pointer-returned-by-shmat-points-at-the-end-of-address-space-which-gives-seg-fau

Comment: Did you consider using Posix shared memory? See [shm_overview(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/shm_overview.7.html)

Answer (score 5):

You can give permissions to the shared memory segment you create. By default only root is allowed access but you can change this while you create the shared memory segment, for example:

```
shmid = shmget(key, SHMSZ, IPC_CREAT | 0666); 
//or
shmid = shmget(key, SHMSZ, IPC_CREAT | 0777);
```

Then you may try and access this shared memory segment as any user.